# Login script produces mismatch error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am developing a registration and login script and I have been modeling my scripts based on Larry Ullan's quickpro guide (along with the php manual and other references).  My registration script works well, but I run into a problem when I try the login script.  I make a query to the DB as such:

```
    $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM registration WHERE email='$ue' AND  pass=SHA1('$p')";
```

I will get the error message:

`The email address and password entered do not match those on file`

If I remove the `AND pass=SHA1('$p')` like this

```
    $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM registration WHERE email='$ue'";
```

The script directs me to a logged in page as it should.

I have been over and over the registration script and the login function script trying to find the disconnect and I just can't see it.  Here is an excerpt from my registration script:

```
    //Check for a password and match against the confirmed password:

    if (!empty($_POST['pass1'])) {

    if ($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2']) {

    $errors[] = 'Your password did not match the confirmed password.';

    }else{

    $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['pass1']));

    }

    }else{

    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';

    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////// password parameters

   if( strlen($p) < 8 ) {

    $errors[]= "Password too short! ";
    }

    if( strlen($p) > 15 ) {

    $errors[]= "Password too long! ";

   }

    if( !preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $p)  {

    $errors[]= "Password must include at least one number! ";

    }


    if( !preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $p) ) {

    $errors[]= "Password must include at least one letter! ";

    }
   if( !preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $p) ) {

    $errors[]= "Password must include at least one CAPS! ";
    }

    if( !preg_match("#\W+#", $p) ) {

    $errors[]= "Password must include at least one symbol! ";

    }   

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And here is my code for the login function script:

```
    function check_login($dbc, $email ='', $pass='') {


    $errors = array(); // Initialize error array.


    //validate email

    if (empty($email)) {

    $errors[]='You forgot to enter your email address.';

    }else{

    $ue = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($email));

    } 


    //validate password
    if (empty($pass)) {

    $errors[]='You forgot to enter your password.';

    }else{

    $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pass));

    } 


    if (empty($errors)) { // if passed validation

    //call to DB at beginning of login script

    //retrieve user id and first name for that email/password combo

    $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM registration WHERE email='$ue' AND  pass=SHA1('$p')";

    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);


    //check results
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {


    //fetch the record

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    return array(true, $row);

    }else{  // not a match

    $errors[]= 'The email address and password entered do not match those on  file';

    }

    }  // End of empty ($errors) IF


    //return false and the errors:

    return array(false, $errors);


    } //End of check_login() function
```

I have tried every debugging technique that I can think of or find searching the internet (doesn't mean I haven't missed something).  I have searched this site and did not see an answer to my problem.  I hope someone has an answer because I really do not know where to go from here.  I have gone over both scripts line by line.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you by chance stored the password in plain text?

Comment: Have you tried echoing what is in your database in the password field and also displaying what your sha1($password) returns?

Comment: There's this new thing called indenting your code that all the cool kids are doing now days. You should try ti.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback developerwjk,  I will try to remember next time.

Answer (score 0):

My oh My!  I found my problem and the answer is embarrassing to say the least.  I wanted to share this so that it may save someone else hours of debugging time.  I offer no excuses as to why I did it but I had set the column width for "pass" at 20 instead of the required 40 character for SHA1.  I really do not like falling on my own sword but hopefully it will save someone else the agony.